# How to layout stuffs on NSView resize without delay?

Tags: macos, cocoa, calayer, nsview, appkit

I am trying to layout several `CALayer`s on NSView resize.
I tried these events, but they all get delayed and it makes the final layout to be done slightly later than the actual view resize, and this makes the final rendering shaky..

```
public class Sample1View: NSView {
    public override func viewWillStartLiveResize() {
        super.viewWillStartLiveResize()
        render()
    }
    public override func viewDidEndLiveResize() {
        super.viewDidEndLiveResize()
        render()
    }
}
```

How do I layout `CALayer`s synchronously without delay?

Answer (score 0):

So far, this is the best way to perform fully synchronous layout.

```
public class Sample1View: NSView {
    public override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        render()
    }
}
```